# add_to_cart() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'product_id' and 'quantity'

Tags: python, django

i am beginner I don't know what to do sorry please help me
Traceback

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\daghe\Dev\ecommerce - Backup\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "C:\Users\daghe\Dev\ecommerce - Backup\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /cart/add/
Exception Value: add_to_cart() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'product_id' and 'quantity'

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import (
    cart_home,
    add_to_cart,
    remove_from_cart,
    checkout_home,
    checkout_done_view
)
app_name = 'carts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', cart_home, name='home'),
    path('checkout/success', checkout_done_view, name='success'),
    path('checkout/', checkout_home, name='checkout'),
    path('add/', add_to_cart, name='add-item'),
    path('remove/<product_id>/', add_to_cart, name='remove-item'),
]
```

views.py

```
    def add_to_cart(request, product_id, quantity):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    cart = Cart(request)
    cart.add(product, product.unit_price, quantity)

def remove_from_cart(request, product_id):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    cart = Cart(request)
    cart.remove(product)

def cart_home(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    return render(request, 'carts/home.html', {"cart":cart})
```

form:

```
2   <form method='POST' action='{% url "cart:add-item" %}' class="form"> {% csrf_token %}
3       <input type='hidden' name='product_id' value='{{ product.id }}' />
4   
5       {% if in_cart %}
6           <button type='submit' class='btn btn-link btn-sm' style="padding:0px;cursor: pointer;">Remove?</button>
7       {% else %}
8           {% if product in cart.products.all %}
9               In cart <button type='submit' class='btn btn-link'>Remove?</button>
10          {% else %}
11              <button type='submit'  class='btn btn-success'>Add to cart</button>
12          {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see multiple mistakes in this :

1.) Parameters missing from url of `add_to_cart`. If

```
def add_to_cart(request, product_id, quantity):
```

is having two arguments. Then url should be something like :

```
path('add/<product_id>/<quantity>/', add_to_cart, name='add-item'),
```

2.) URL for remove is also calling `add_to_cart`. It should be :

```
path('remove/<product_id>/', remove_from_cart, name='remove-item'),
```

Comment: thank you but now i am getting this error with the form i added above "Reverse for 'add-item' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cart\\/add\\/(?P<product_id>[^/]+)\\/(?P<product_quantity>[^/]+)\\/$']

Comment: in form action, url needs arguments. `<form method='POST' action='{% url "cart:add-item" product.id product.quantity %}' class="form"> {% csrf_token %}`.. considering quantity is inside product(for product.quantity).

Comment: "Reverse for 'add-item' with arguments '(2, '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cart\\/add\\/(?P<product_id>[^/]+)\\/(?P<quantity>[^/]+)\\/$']"
i am getting this now thank so much for helping me btw

Comment: Your quantity is Null. Second argument does not contain anything. Please make sure you are getting quantity in HTML template and passing the same to url action.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_to_cart(request, product_id, quantity):
```

This method seeks for two values. product_id and quantity.

In your urls.py provide the two values also.

So urls.py will be:

```
path('add/<product_id>/<product_quantity>/', add_to_cart, name='add-item'),
```

In form

```
<form method='POST' action='{% url "cart:add-item" product.id product.quantity %}' class="form"> {% csrf_token %}
  <input type='hidden' name='product_id' value='{{ product.id }}' />

  {% if in_cart %}
       <button type='submit' class='btn btn-link btn-sm' style="padding:0px;cursor: pointer;">Remove?</button>
  {% else %}
       {% if product in cart.products.all %}
           In cart <button type='submit' class='btn btn-link'>Remove? 
</button>
     {% else %}
         <button type='submit'  class='btn btn-success'>Add to 
cart</button>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: thank you but now i am getting this error with the form i added above "Reverse for 'add-item' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cart\\/add\\/(?P<product_id>[^/]+)\\/(?P<product_quantity>[^/]+)\\/$']"